# room id - philips TV

Tags: javascript, settings, lan, television

how to read the room number of the settings of the TV / TVs via the network. 
I can save number room in TV by remote control -> professional settings -> Room id

I needs to show something at the appropriate TV.

**Update**

```
function Room(){ 
    var JAPITObjForWIXPSvc = new CreateJAPITObjectForWIXPSvc(); 
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Cookie = 1040;   
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CmdType = "Change"; 
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Fun = "ProfessionalSettingsControl"; 
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CommandDetails = { 
        "ProfessionalSettingsParameters" : [ "RoomID" ]  lert(RoomID);
    }; 
    sendWIxPCommand(JAPITObjForWIXPSvc); 
    delete JAPITObjForWIXPSvc; 
}
```

I do not know whether a good trail goes, he needs to pull the number of TVs hotel I am definitely sure about the javascript help mi

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? --- (This can be done using JS? Are you sure?)

Comment: function Room(){
    var JAPITObjForWIXPSvc = new CreateJAPITObjectForWIXPSvc();  JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Cookie         = 1040;   JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CmdType        = "Change";
  JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Fun            = "ProfessionalSettingsControl";
     JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CommandDetails = {
    "ProfessionalSettingsParameters" :
    [   "RoomID"
    ]   lert(RoomID);
     };
     sendWIxPCommand(JAPITObjForWIXPSvc);
     delete JAPITObjForWIXPSvc;
I do not know whether a good trail goes , he needs to pull the number of TVs hotel
I am definitely sure about the javascript
help mi

Answer (score 0):

```js
function RoomId()
 {
    var JAPITObjForWIXPSvc = new CreateJAPITObjectForWIXPSvc();
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Cookie         = 1040;
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CmdType        = "Request";
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Fun            = "RoomID";
    sendWIxPCommand(JAPITObjForWIXPSvc);
    delete JAPITObjForWIXPSvc;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SetRoomRoom()
   {
    var JAPITObjForWIXPSvc = new CreateJAPITObjectForWIXPSvc();
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Cookie         = 1040;
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CmdType        = "Change";
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.Fun            = "ProfessionalSettingsControl";
    JAPITObjForWIXPSvc.CommandDetails = 
    {
    "ProfessionalSettingsParameters" :
    [
    "SwitchOnSource",
    "TVModel",
    "SerialNumber",
    "RoomID" : 0222,
    "NetworkSettings",
    "NetworkStatus",
    "PrimaryAudioLanguage",
    "PrimarySubtitleLanguage",
    "VolumeLimits",
    "SystemUIURL"]
  
   sendWIxPCommand(JAPITObjForWIXPSvc);
   delete JAPITObjForWIXPSvc;
   );
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to do, maybe somebody helps ?

Comment: It's really hard to know what you're trying to do. How are you writing JavaScript for a tv for instance.

Comment: Connect dashboard write url, and I have in my computer serwer xampp, 
I know to work because the other commands work in tvyet possibility of web service

Comment: This is the kind go information to put in the question.